# How to format a range of cells in python using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

How do I write a format to a range of cells.

What I am doing is looping over the column names in a list from oracle, and formatting the columns as dates, where the column name starts with "DT".  But I also want to make the entire data range have borders.

I would like to really apply the date format to the columns, and then separately apply the borders...but the last format applies wins, and the application of the borders overwrites the date formatting on the columns.

Ideally I want to blast the data range with borders, and then apply date formats to the date columns, while retaining the borders.

Can you select a range and then apply formatting or do range intersections as you can in VBA?

```
  # Generate EXCEL File
        xl_filename = "DQ_Valid_Status_Check.xlsx"

        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(xl_filename)

        # Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

        date_format = workbook.add_format(
            {'num_format': 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'})

        border = workbook.add_format()
        border.set_bottom()
        border.set_top()
        border.set_left()
        border.set_right()

        worksheet_info = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet_info.name = "Information"
        worksheet_info.write('A1', 'Report Description:', bold)
        worksheet_info.write('B1', 'ARIEL Data Quality Report for Checking Authorisation Status of Marketing Applications')
        worksheet_info.write('A2', 'Report Date:', bold)
        worksheet_info.write('B2', datetime.datetime.now(), date_format)

        worksheet_data = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet_data.name = "DQ Report"
        worksheet_data.write_row('A1', col_names)

        for i in range(len(results)):
            print("result " + str(i) + ' of' + str(len(results)))
            print(results[i])
            worksheet_data.write_row('A' + str(i + 2), results[i])
            #worksheet_data.set_row(i + 2, None, border)




        # add borders
        for i in range(len(results)):
            worksheet_data.set_row(i + 2, None, border)

        # format date columns
        for i in range(len(col_names)):
            col_name = col_names[i]
            if col_name.startswith("DT"):
                print(col_name)
                worksheet_data.set_column(i, i, None, date_format)

        workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the FAQ, it is not currently possible to [format a range of cells at once](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html#q-can-i-apply-a-format-to-a-range-of-cells-in-one-go), but a future feature might allow this.

You could create Format objects containing multiple format properties and apply your custom format to each cell as you write to it. See ["Creating and using a Format Object"](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#creating-and-using-a-format-object).

Comment: Thanks, I am iterating over rows and writing each row rather than individual cells.  Iterating over an Oracle data set.

Comment: The "future feature" referred to in the FAQ is formally registered as [issue #111](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/111) on the project's GitHub page. Unfortunately, that issue has been closed and we cannot expect any work *within the XlsxWriter project* on such a feature. However, several alternatives were presented in that discussion, and there also might be relevant helper packages published on GitHub or PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

To apply borders to all columns at once you can do something like:

```
border = workbook.add_format({'border':2})
worksheet_info.set_column(first_col=0, last_col=10, cell_format=border)
```

And to retain the border format you can modify your date_format to:

```
date_format = workbook.add_format(
        {'num_format': 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss',
         'border': 2})
```

Comment: I want to apply borders to everything, but then layer on date formatting to columns after applying borders across the entire data range.  In VBA I would create a range intersection of the data range and a column and format that range.  But you can layer on formats...doesn’t the last format win in xlsxWriter?

Comment: The last wins, but you can have one format variable that has date format and borders simultaneously. You don't need to apply just one thing in each format instance.

Comment: But the issue is I only want borders to the end of the data.  I tried creating a format with borders and date formatting and applying it to the column, but it took borders all the way down...would be great to select a range and not loop through each cell.

Comment: you can have something like: 

workbook.add_format( {
    'num_format': 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss', 
    'border': 2,
    'font_size': 15,
    'bold': True,
    'bg_color': 'red'
})   

And all these work togheter

Comment: Wait. You want something like a square around your data, or a single line in the end ? not in each cell ?

Comment: 10,000 row data set.  Each cell in the 10,000 row data set with borders around the data (all sides in each cell).  5 columns then with a date format.

Comment: As you can’t select ranges, you seem to have to apply it to each row, column or cell.  So if you don’t want formatting to apply to any entries row or column, as in my case, seems only cell formatting works.